# Why did my floors disappear?

Tags: tiny-tower

After an update on Tiny Tower today, 3 of my most recent floors including 1 I was building disappeared. I'm now back to 180 floors. Any ideas what has happened?

Can I get these floors back?

Comment: Is there still an option to build more floors? Wondering if maybe they added a floor cap?

Comment: Strange - I still have 186 floors and and just built a 187th. (185 is the last CONSTRUCTED floor with apartments or a business.) What platform (iOS, Android) are you using? What version of TT is it? (Version is shown at the top middle after tapping Menu.)

Comment: Given the now-deleted non-answers, it seems like this might be a recent bug